# Вопрос по использованию библиотеки FFMpeg в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

Привет всем! У меня есть вопрос по использованию библиотеки FFMpeg в Laravel.

Как я могу из одного видео получить несколько видео разными качествами?

Сам код:

```
    $video = $ffmpeg->open("D:/PROfit/PHP/htdocs/VideoTasc/public/file/".$fileName);
    $frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(37));
    $name = explode('.',$fileName);
    $n= $name[0];
    $frame->save('img/'.$n.'.jpg');
```

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в текстовом виде.

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в текстовом виде.

Comment: Так а в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже нашел решения

```
  $video
        ->filters()
        ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
        ->synchronize();

    $frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10));
    $name = explode('.',$fileName);
    $n= $name[0];

    $video->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264'), "file/".$n.'-320.mp4');
```